# Accessing nested class in C++

Tags: c++

I came across this question in an online test that I was taking. The task is to alter this program to get rid of compilation errors.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

class Vehicle
{
public:
    static Car* createCar()
    {
        return new Car;
    }

    class Car
    {
        public:
            string name;
    };
private:
    int seats;
};

void useVehicle()
{
    Vehicle::Car *c = Vehicle::createCar();
    c->name = "BMW";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    useVehicle();
    return 0;
}
```

The compilations errors are like:
`error: ‘Car’ does not name a type`
`error: ‘string’ does not name a type`
In function `void useVehicle()`:
`error: ‘createCar’ is not a member of ‘Vehicle’`

How do I get it right ? I tried few things but could not resolve these errors.

Comment: Be more specific on what you tried and what happened when you did.

Comment: [Here is a working version of your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b5a879f37c395a9f5701b9fbbee730f7-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: Are nested classes a C++ 11 thing?  I haven't seen them before in this language.

Comment: @Panzercrisis: No, they're not. They were standard in C++98 as well.

Comment: You can easily fix the errors, without changing the program's output, by simplifying it to `int main(){}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> error: ‘Car’ does not name a type

At the point of

```
static Car* createCar()
```

Car is not yet known. Move the definition of class `Car` above the function

> error: ‘string’ does not name a type In function ‘void useVehicle()’:

```
#include <string>
```

also use `std::` to qualify `string`

> error: ‘createCar’ is not a member of ‘Vehicle’

This error will disappear once you fix the other two issues. The compiler wasn't able to parse the function declaration because it didn't know what its return type was.